# acess google calendar to retrieve events specific to a date

Tags: android, google-calendar-api

I am trying to access google calendar in android .. 
I am using google java client api (gdata api not working in android.. tried a lot.. some issue with library )..
I want to access events within a specific date range..
say I want to retrieve all the events inbetween date range 3-march-2011 to 5 march 2011
Can anyone tell me how to do that ?

I am using the following example as base
http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/source/browse?repo=samples#hg%2Fcalendar-v2-atom-android-sample